# send emails to facebook friends from an iPhone Application using the GRAPH API

Tags: iphone

i am developing an iPhone application and in need to send emails to the user's friends present in his/her facebook account.So far i hav been able to log in the facebook account and retrieve user's list of friends.But cant seem to find a way to send emails to the friends.I need to do this using the GRAPH API.I dont want their email addresses but juat a work around to send them emails.

Answer (score 0):

So you gets the user details. You have to get email ID for friends. To do so you have to set permission. Use the cod ebelow to set permission

```
NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
    @"user_likes", 
    @"read_stream",@"email"
    nil];
[facebook authorize:permissions];
[permissions release];
```

After this when you run your program, you can find email Id of each friend. Get it and send mail

Comment: this permission should be given at the time of login,right ?
Did that,but it didnt return me email